# Loading data with Async Await messes up data

Tags: c#, entity-framework, mvvm, async-await, observablecollection

I update my MVVM application to fetch data with the async and await, but for some reason my ObservableCollection's get messed up; 
I load other Collections at the same time, like Persons, Locations, and they are sometimes mixed together.

How/why does this happen and how can I solve this?

**ViewModel**:

```
private async void Load()
{
    Agents = await DAL.Agent.LoadAsync();
}
```

OR (for testing purposes)

```
private async void Load()
{
    var task = DAL.Agent.LoadAsync();
    task.Wait();
    Agents = await task;
}
```

OR (for testing purposes)

```
public async void Load()
{
    AgentsVW = await Task.Run(() => DAL.Agent.LoadVW(null));
}
```

**DAL**:

```
public static Task<ObservableCollection<Models.Agent>> LoadAsync()
{
    return Task.Factory.StartNew(() => Load());
}

    public static ObservableCollection<Models.Agent> Load()
    {
        ObservableCollection<Models.Agent> Collection = new ObservableCollection<Models.Agent>();
        Collection.Add(new Models.Agent());

        try
        {
            using (DAL.EF.csEntities_PersonData ef = new DAL.EF.csEntities_PersonData())
            {
                var x = (from r in ef.usp_tblAgents_S(null) select r);

                foreach (var item in x)
                {
                    Collection.Add(new Models.Agent()
                    {
                        //Fields
                    });
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
           //Log it
        }
            return Collection;
    }
```

**EDIT**
The values are correct, but it just DISPLAYS wrong/other values in the comboboxes.

Comment: Can you be more specific? Or try code piece by piece in function not in task.

Comment: @Mertuarez When I leave out the Task and Async & Await, everything just works fine. It is after the implementation things started going wrong.

Comment: return await Task.Factory.StartNew. Start and new look strange to me.

Comment: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pfxteam/2011/10/24/task-run-vs-task-factory-startnew/

Comment: Read [Stephen Cleary ](http://stackoverflow.com/users/263693/stephen-cleary)'s [blog](http://blog.stephencleary.com/ "Stephen Cleary (the blog)") [post](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/08/startnew-is-dangerous.html "StartNew is Dangerous") on how dangerous can be to use `Task.Factory.StartNew` with `async-await`.

Comment: Why aren't you using EF's async API if that's what you want?

Comment: What's the code calling the `Load`method on your view model. `async void` is, usually, the cause of problems like this.

Comment: @PauloMorgado Interesting read. The Load Method is the second method in my DAL section in this post.

Comment: @PauloMorgado Yes... I just don't want the UI to stall... that's the main goal I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: @Hypenate: There's a lot wrong with the code you posted, but nothing that will cause wrong data to be returned. Please post a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).
The wrong: [using StartNew](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/08/startnew-is-dangerous.html), [fake-async wrappers](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pfxteam/2012/03/24/should-i-expose-asynchronous-wrappers-for-synchronous-methods/), [using fake async when true async calls exist](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/taskrun-etiquette-examples-using.html)

Comment: @StephenCleary Could it be because the ObserservableCollection is not threadsafe things go wrong? I'm running out of clue's here :)

Comment: @Hypenate: No, because it's never simultaneously accessed by multiple threads. Please post a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @StephenCleary If I would be able to create an MCVE I would maybe know where the issue is.
I don't know how to reproduce this, I just notice that the data of the other Collections from other ViewModels are seen in Collection where they do not belong, sometimes. I did not have this issue when I was not using the Async & Wait and Task.Run features.

Comment: @Hypenate: `If I would be able to create an MCVE I would maybe know where the issue is` - exactly. Usually, during the process of trimming down to an MCVE, you'll find the problem yourself.

Comment: @StephenCleary Thanks for the help but I have no clue what is going on. 
I have reverted the app back to synchrone as there everything works normal this way. Too bad though.